# XAMPP, cURL, PHP - cURL not executing

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am trying to access my credit card clearing company through cURL from home. 
For some reason I cannot execute the command.

(I did remove the remark from extension=php_curl.dll in my php.ini and restart the server)

```
$url = 'https://secure.cc-company-address.com/clearingPage.aspx';

$fields = array(
            'codepage'=>'65001',
            'terminalnumber'=>'0',
            'UserName'=>'leaping',
            'SumToBill'=>'1.9',
            'Operation'=>'2'
            );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }

$fields_string=substr($fields_string,0,strlen($fields_string)-1);

$curl = curl_init();
if(!$curl)
    echo "curl not inititalized.";
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.$fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);

if($result)
    echo " curl executed. ";
else
    echo " curl failed. ";

curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: You should turn on your computer. No but seriously, without any error messages it could be anything, you have to provide us with more information.

Comment: I just found curl_error... it says: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed curl failed.

Comment: found a quick and dirty solution: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); which will accept all SSL protected sites

Comment: and even better: the scond option: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not debug it properly! after you start curl_exec

```
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$httpHeaders = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($httpcode  && $contents!='')
{
    makeLog('calls ', $URL.' resp c:'.$httpcode.' r:'.$contents); 
}
else if($httpcode)
{
    makeLog('calls ', $URL.' resp c:'.$httpcode); 
}

function makeLog($function , $message='')
{
    $myFile = "errorLogs.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+');
    fwrite($fh , "\n\r\n\r".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].': '.$message.' -'.$function."\n\r\n\r");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` in my case it worked with Pushover